# Retrieving an EditText value from Tablayout

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-tablayout

I need help on how to retrieve the userinput value from an edittext in a tablayout. I have 4 tabs and each tab have the same editText widget meaning that I only implemented one edittext view. Problem is, if I put a value in each editText I have no idea how to retrieve them since I don't know how to find the position for each editText I even need to put them inside my database which is in sqlite. Would someone guide me. Thanks.

PS. The code will be added if requested.

EDIT:

My_Notes_Add_Main.java

```
package com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite.addNotes;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite.R;
import com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite.mynote_databases.DatabaseHelper;
import com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite.notes.DataModel;

public class My_Notes_Add_Main extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private final int numOfPages = 4; //viewpager has 4 pages
    private final String[] pageTitle = {"Terms", "Definition", "Syntax", "Code"};
    private ImageButton addNew;

    My_Notes_Add_MyPagerAdapter adapter = new My_Notes_Add_MyPagerAdapter( null, numOfPages);

    DatabaseHelper db;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_notes_add_main);

        db = new DatabaseHelper(this);        

        addNew = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.addNew);
        addNewTerms();

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar1);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);

        for (int i = 0; i < numOfPages; i++) {
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(pageTitle[i]));
        }

        //set gravity for tab bar
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new My_Notes_Add_MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), numOfPages);

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(onTabSelectedListener(viewPager));

    }

    private TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener onTabSelectedListener(final ViewPager pager) {
        return new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                pager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        };
    }

  /**  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_notes_add_main_menu, menu);        
        return true;
    } */

    public void addNewTerms(){
        addNew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                ArrayList<String> listNotes= new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
                    My_Notes_Add_TabFragment fragment = adapter.getFragment(i);
                    if(fragment != null)
                        listNotes.add(fragment.getText());



                }

                DataModel model = new DataModel(listNotes.get(0),listNotes.get(1),
                                 listNotes.get(2),listNotes.get(3));

                db.InsertNewRecord(model); 
            }

    });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }






}
```

My_Notes_Add_MyPagerAdapter.java

```
package com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite.addNotes;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.util.SparseArray;

public class My_Notes_Add_MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
     int numOfTabs;
    private final SparseArray<Fragment> mPageReferences = new SparseArray<Fragment>();



    public My_Notes_Add_MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int numOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.numOfTabs = numOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        My_Notes_Add_TabFragment fragment = (My_Notes_Add_TabFragment) My_Notes_Add_TabFragment.getInstance(position);
        mPageReferences.put(position, fragment);
        return fragment;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return numOfTabs;
    }

    public My_Notes_Add_TabFragment getFragment(int key) {
        return (My_Notes_Add_TabFragment) mPageReferences.get(key);
     }



    }
```

My_Notes_Add_TabFragment.java

```
package com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite.addNotes;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite.R;

public class My_Notes_Add_TabFragment extends Fragment {

    private int position;
    public TextView content;
    //private ImageView image;



    public static Fragment getInstance(int position) {
        My_Notes_Add_TabFragment f = new My_Notes_Add_TabFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("position", position);
        f.setArguments(args);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //get data from Argument
        position = getArguments().getInt("position");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_notes_add_tab_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


        content = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);





    }

    public String getText(){
           return content.getText().toString();
        }






}
```

DatabaseHelper.java
Note the commented insertion of database it was done in order to test if my db is working

```
package com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite.mynote_databases;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite.notes.DataModel;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBASE = "my_notes";
    public static final String TBLMYNOTES = "tblnotes";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;
    public static final String NOTE_TERM = "note_term";
    public static final String NOTE_ID = "note_id";
    public static final String NOTE_DEF = "note_def";
    public static final String NOTE_SYNTAX = "note_syntax";
    public static final String NOTE_CODE = "note_code";

    public int currentID;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBASE, null, DBVERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+TBLMYNOTES+" ("+ NOTE_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+NOTE_TERM+" TEXT, "+NOTE_DEF+" TEXT, "+NOTE_SYNTAX+" TEXT, "+NOTE_CODE+" TEXT )");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TBLMYNOTES);

        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void InsertNewRecord( DataModel datamodel ) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues db_values = new ContentValues();
        db_values.put(NOTE_TERM, datamodel.getTerm());
        db_values.put(NOTE_DEF, datamodel.getDefinition());
        db_values.put(NOTE_SYNTAX, datamodel.getSyntax());
        db_values.put(NOTE_CODE, datamodel.getCode());
        /** int countArr = values.size();

        for( int i = 0; i < countArr; i++  ) {

            db_values.put( fields.get(i), values.get(i) );

        }
*/      
        db.insert(TBLMYNOTES, null, db_values);

        db.close();
    }


    public Cursor getAllData(String tblname) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor result = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+tblname, null);

        return result;
    }

    /**
     * @return
     */
    public List<DataModel> getAllDataModel(){

        List<DataModel> dataList = new ArrayList<DataModel>();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TBLMYNOTES;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        while(c.moveToNext()){
            /**     DataModel model= new DataModel();
            model.setId(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(0)));
            model.setTerm(c.getString(1));
            model.setDefinition(c.getString(2));
            model.setSyntax(c.getString(3));
            model.setCode(c.getString(4));
    */  
            int index0 = c.getColumnIndex(NOTE_ID);
            int index1 = c.getColumnIndex(NOTE_TERM);
            int index2 = c.getColumnIndex(NOTE_DEF);
            int index3 = c.getColumnIndex(NOTE_SYNTAX);
            int index4 = c.getColumnIndex(NOTE_CODE);

            int id = c.getInt(index0);

            String term = c.getString(index1);
            String def = c.getString(index2);
            String syn = c.getString(index3);
            String code = c.getString(index4);
            DataModel model = new DataModel(id, term, def, syn, code);
            dataList.add(model);

        }

        return dataList;
    }

    public int DeleteRecord(String tblname, String strField, String strValue) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        int status = db.delete(TBLMYNOTES , " "+strField+" = ? ", new String[] { strValue });

        return status;
    }

    public int UpdateRecord(String tblname, ArrayList<String> Fields, ArrayList<String> Values) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues db_values = new ContentValues();

        int countMaxArr = Fields.size();

        String strFieldID = Fields.get(0);
        String strFieldValue = Values.get(0);


        for( int i = 0; i < countMaxArr; i++ ) {

            db_values.put(Fields.get(i), Values.get(i));

        }

        int status = db.update(TBLMYNOTES, db_values, strFieldID+" = ? ", new String[] { strFieldValue });

        return status;
    }

    public void setcurrID(int ID) {     
        currentID = ID;
    }       

    public int getcurrID() {
        return currentID;
    }


    public Cursor getRecordByID(String tblname, String Fieldname, String Fieldvalue) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor result = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ TBLMYNOTES+" WHERE "+Fieldname+" = "+Fieldvalue, null);

        return result;

    }


}
```

DataModel.java

```
package com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite.notes;

public class DataModel {

    String term_;
    String definition_;
    int id_;
    String syntax_;
    String code_;

    public DataModel(){

    }

    public DataModel(int id, String term, String def, String syntax, String code) {
        this.term_ = term;
        this.id_ = id;
        this.definition_=def;
        this.syntax_=syntax;
        this.code_=code;
    }

    public DataModel(String term, String def, String syntax, String code) {
        this.term_ = term;
        this.definition_=def;
        this.syntax_=syntax;
        this.code_=code;
    }

    public String getTerm() {
        return term_;
    } 

    public String getDefinition(){
        return definition_;
    }

    public String getSyntax() {
        return syntax_;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code_;
    }


    public int getId() {
        return id_;
    }

    public void setTerm(String term){
        this.term_= term;
    }

    public void setId(int id){
        this.id_= id;
    }
    public void setDefinition(String definition){
        this.definition_= definition;
    }
    public void setSyntax(String syntax){
        this.syntax_= syntax;
    }
    public void setCode(String code){
        this.code_= code;
    }
}
```

LogCat

```
03-14 23:37:37.230: D/AndroidRuntime(4640): Shutting down VM
03-14 23:37:37.230: W/dalvikvm(4640): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x55d52b20)
03-14 23:37:37.230: I/Process(4640): Sending signal. PID: 4640 SIG: 9
03-14 23:37:37.230: D/AndroidRuntime(4640): procName from cmdline: com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite
03-14 23:37:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(4640): in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite
03-14 23:37:37.230: D/AndroidRuntime(4640): file written successfully with content: com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite StringBuffer : ;com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite
03-14 23:37:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(4640): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-14 23:37:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(4640): Process: com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite, PID: 4640
03-14 23:37:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(4640): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite/com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite.addNotes.My_Notes_Add_Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-14 23:37:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(4640):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
03-14 23:37:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(4640):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
03-14 23:37:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(4640):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-14 23:37:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(4640):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
03-14 23:37:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(4640):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-14 23:37:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(4640):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-14 23:37:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(4640):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
03-14 23:37:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(4640):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-14 23:37:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(4640):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-14 23:37:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(4640):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
03-14 23:37:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(4640):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
03-14 23:37:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(4640):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-14 23:37:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(4640): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-14 23:37:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(4640):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:256)
03-14 23:37:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(4640):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
03-14 23:37:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(4640):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
03-14 23:37:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(4640):     at com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite.mynote_databases.DatabaseHelper.<init>(DatabaseHelper.java:30)
03-14 23:37:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(4640):     at com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite.addNotes.My_Notes_Add_Main.<init>(My_Notes_Add_Main.java:24)
03-14 23:37:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(4640):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
03-14 23:37:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(4640):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
03-14 23:37:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(4640):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1064)
03-14 23:37:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(4640):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
03-14 23:37:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(4640):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: please post some code

Comment: @g2o updated my post now.

Comment: sorry for the late answer, problem with captcha.

Comment: @g2o updated my post in order to show the DataModel code as well as the corresponding database.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working sample

```
public class My_Notes_Add_MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    int numOfTabs;
    private final SparseArray<Fragment> mPageReferences = new SparseArray<>();

    public My_Notes_Add_MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int numOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.numOfTabs = numOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
       My_Notes_Add_TabFragment fragment = My_Notes_Add_TabFragment.getInstance(position);
       mPageReferences.put(position, fragment);
       return     }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return numOfTabs;
    }   

    public My_Notes_Add_TabFragment getFragment(int key) {
       return (My_Notes_Add_TabFragment) mPageReferences.get(key);
    }

}
```

In your fragment  My_Notes_Add_TabFragment.java add a `getText` method

```
public String getText(){
   return content.getText().toString();
}
```

How to use it. In your My_Notes_Add_Main.java

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    List<String> listNotes= new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
        My_Notes_Add_TabFragment fragment = adapter.getFragment(i);
        if(fragment != null)
            listNotes.add(fragment.getText());
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this,
                            "You need to fill " + pageTitle[i], Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
            return;
        }
    }

    DataModel model = new DataModel(yourId,listNotes.get(0),listNotes.get(1),
                     listNotes.get(2),listNotes.get(3))
    //create your save to DB method with listText parameter
    yourSaveToDB(listNotes);
}
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: thanks I'll try it. By the way what if I have a recyclerView that displays only one Values from the database and when it is click it will get the rest of the values from the database to the edittext in another tablayout with the same concept of code as from that of mine above.

Comment: I'm having trouble with your last code where I have to put my saveDB. I've got this constructor of a DataModel which is use when inserting new data 'DataModel(int id, String, String, String, String)'. How could I modify the listNotes in order to match the constructor which is the DataModel?

Comment: umm what is Datamodel?

Comment: Please if you find values from all EditText of your ViewPager, mark the question as solved :)

Comment: I'm still having troubles with saving the DB yet based on your last codes. I'll update my post. I'm going to add my DataModel.java and Database.

Comment: Ok I understand that all other elements are string from each tabs, but where `id` is coming from?

Comment: @g20 as you can see there's 2 DataModel constructor with one having a parameter of id and the other having none. That id actually comes from my database which is just auto incremented.

Comment: I edited my answer, if everything is fine please mark as solved ;)

Comment: @g20 I can't access my My_Notes_Add_Main.java . I'm getting a null pointer exception. I'll write the logcat. By the way I've modified some of your codes like referencing a static method to a non-static so all my codes have no errors now except that I'm having a null pointer exception.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106258/discussion-between-g2o-and-david-diaz).